# Bokeh is not working with Apache >eppelin

Tags: bokeh, apache-zeppelin

I have installed Bokeh with pip, but it's not working in >eppelin.

It shows:

> RuntimeError: no display hook installed for notebook type 'zeppelin'

Answer (score 1):

To use Bokeh in Zeppelin notebooks, you will need to install the separate `bkzep` package:

https://github.com/zjffdu/bkzep

Comment: And there's one bokeh tutorial in zeppelin, hope it is helpful for you. https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL3pqZmZkdS9mZTljOTJjMzFjYzc0ZGYxOTNmODI3OTgxOGM0Njc1OS9ub3RlLmpzb24